# How can I use replaceText() to remove double periods in a google doc?

Tags: google-apps-script

The body of my google doc contains this text: "testing.."". I'd like to edit this and any other double periods (..) to one period (.). The code would presumably look something like this:

```
function removeDoublePeriods() {

var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody();
body.replaceText('..','.');

//Result: "....." //doesn't work

}
```

It's obvious that period has a defined function in RegExpr, but nothing I've tried has solved the problem. I've tried (''.'','.'), ('\..','.'), ('.*','.'), and others. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  let body = doc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("\\.\\.",'.');
}
```

Comment: [Explanation in Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement), `replaceText()` accepts the `searchPattern` regex as string, so `'..'` would be two instances of any character and `'\..'` would be a literal period and then any other character. Untested, but what you probably need is `'\.\.'`.

Comment: That makes sense and is one of the options I tried: body.replaceText('\.\.','.'); But it didn't work. Replaced all characters with ... . Open to more ideas.

Comment: I also tried this: body.replaceText('\.\.','\.'). Also, didn't work.